# Adding Ecopoxy layer to curing Liquid Glass layer in live edge project

Tags: epoxy, live-edge

I have a 42" white oak round that is 3" thick. I poured [Liquid glass epoxy resin](https://smile.amazon.com/Epoxy-Resin-Crystal-Clear-Liquid/dp/B07PXGFGCS/ref=sr_1_9?crid=338XEMWAM2ZBQ&keywords=eco%20epoxy&qid=1660531192&sprefix=eco%20epoxy%2Caps%2C82&sr=8-9&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.18ed3cb5-28d5-4975-8bc7-93deae8f9840) in the checked cracks (0.5" wide) in it last night. It filled only about 1" deep (darn leaks).  I don't have enough liquid glass to finish the project, but I have some [Ecopoxy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0829S1SWQ).

Question :

1. Once the Liquid Glass is hard (but still tacky), can I fill in the remaining 2" with Ecopoxy?

Even if the bond between the Liquid glass and Ecopoxy isn't great, presumably there'd be enough wood contact for the Ecopoxy to bond to.  My only concern is that the Ecopoxy could act like a solvent and damage the still curing Liquid Glass.

Comment: I don't know much about your 2 products, but I do know I have poured several different layers of epoxy  on each other with no ill affects, I generally waited until that previous pour was fully cured, and as long as I kept sawdust from settling on the curing layer, the next layer merged perfectly with the first (visually)

Comment: This is by no means direct experience, but I've watched a bunch of Youtube videos about deep-pour epoxy furniture-making, and pouring the next layer after 1-3 days seems fairly common. It's not an issue of bonding, rather one of heat. The epoxy curing process is rather exothermic (produces a lot of heat), and this can lead to anything from warpage to fire. A lot of the people I watch seem to pour in ~1" layers when doing large areas, like river tables. It's not as big a deal if you're doing things like filling relatively small cracks and checks, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the Liquid Glass is hard (but still tacky), can I fill in the remaining 2" with Ecopoxy?

I don't see why not **if** that volume of Exopoxy is safe to pour in a single shot.

But, this is based on the assumption that the two products are similar enough chemically that they're directly compatible (as two conventional epoxies with similar properties would be).

Given the unknown chemistry differences perhaps the only authoritative answer you could get for this might be the manufacturer of Ecopoxy themselves.